# AspNetCore, project.fragment.lock.json, and multiple configured platforms

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core, project.json

I have an AspNetCore project which references another project, which builds for both the AnyCpu and x64 platforms, and I need both platforms supported (I have legacy projects which need AnyCpu, but only the x64 platform is supported by AspNetCore).

So I need the x64 platform to be used when building my AspNetCore project.  The problem is that my AnyCpu configuration for the referenced project has OutputDirectory bin\debug, while for my x64 configuration the OutputDirectory is bin\x64\debug.  The trouble is that inside of the project.fragment.lock.json file that is generated (and I'm not even sure if its Visual Studio or something else that generates the project.fragment.lock.json), I always see the dll referenced via the path bin\debug, not bin\debug\x64.

I've worked around it by making the output directory for the referenced project the same regardless of platform, but that is a bad solution, as it often results in errors due to using dlls built for the wrong platform (and a host of other issues).  Has anyone else found away around this?

I've tried a fair amount of hacks around it, including modifying the xproj for the AspNetCore project to try to inject the platform, and modifying the csproj file for the referenced project, setting a default Platform, but I'm still trying and will hopefully add an answer if I find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've managed to tease out, as well as the work-around for the issue I've settled upon.

Initially I thought that when building the AspNetCore project that, since there is no sign of a $(Platform) value in that project, that Visual Studio was building those projects without setting $(Platform), but that wasn't correct.  In fact, for AspNetCore projects (or any that use xproj files), $(Platform) is explicitly set to AnyCPU, and it is not possible, as far as I can tell, to alter this.  If you try to set the platform to x64 for a DotNetCore project in the Configuration Manager, it will not show any error, but it won't have any effect; the next time you open the Configuration Manager it will show it as set back to AnyCPU.

So, given that I can't control what $(Platform) gets set to, and that it is nailed down to AnyCPU, but that I require that PlatformTarget gets set to x64, and that I need a different OutputPath for x64 vs. AnyCPU, I had no choice but to start controlling this using $(Configuration) instead.

So that's the work-around: create a DebugDotNetCore configuration and a ReleaseDotNetCore configuration in the solution, and in any project used by an AspNetCore project, create PropertyGroups that look like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'DebugDotNetCore'">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <OutputPath>bin\DebugDotNetCore\</OutputPath>
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then, in the Configuration Manager, make the DebugDotNetCore configuration use the DebugDotNetCore in each project that you've added it to.  And also add the configuration for the AspNetCore projects, and use it for those too (or else none of this won't have any effect).  Until this is fixed I use the DebugDotNetCore and ReleaseDotNetCore configurations when building my AspNetCore projects and the Debug and Release configurations when building everything else.

Oh, also notice that I don't check $(Platform) in the new PropertyGroups, so the begin tags don't look like they usually do, which is more like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
```

That's because any difference based on $(Platform) won't make sense.

I also included an xml comment near these, basically telling the next developer with the misfortune of running into this that setting anything differently, depending on platform won't work as expected since PlatformTarget must be set to x64, while $(Platform) must be set to AnyCPU.

I can't wait to get rid of this, but it appears that Microsoft won't be fixing this until the next version of Visual Studio comes out, at which point project.json will be removed, and (I hope), DotNetCore will finally truly be integrated with Visual Studio.